# Issue with creating sub graphs from Los Angeles County graph

Tags: python, openstreetmap, networkx, osmnx

I am trying to extract a subgraph using `networkx` `ego_graph` function from Los Angeles County graph.
When i plot this graph and compare it with graph generated from `graph_from_point` (which looks correct), they seem to be completely different.

**Here is my code**

```
G = ox.graph_from_place('Los Angeles County, California, USA')

node = ox.get_nearest_node(G, (34.6806, -118.1435))
```

**Subgraph from networkx**

```
sub_graph = nx.ego_graph(G, node, radius=2500, distance='length')

ox.plot_graph(sub_graph)
```

[image]

**graph_from_point**

```
g = ox.graph_from_point((34.6806, -118.1435), dist = 2500)
ox.plot_graph(g)
```

[image]

Both sub_graph and g look completely different.
Am i doing anything wrong here?